# Typeahead.js custom template with basic local data

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I need help. I'm trying to use [Typeahead.js custom template](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates) where in data1VALUE + data1DESCRITPION are suggested but when a user selects a suggestion only data1VALUE will be the value of the text box. But instead of fetching the data using json, I would like to just get the data locally, like [this](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#the-basics).

So far, the codes I have

HTML

```
 <div id="custom-templates">
 <input class="typeahead" type="text">
 </div>
```

JS

```
 var productlist = new Bloodhound({
 datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
 queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

local: [
  { "product": "GSPEN", "description": "Pen" },
  { "product": "GSTS", "description": "Tissue" },
  ]
});

$('#custom-templates .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
name: 'productlist',
display: 'product ',
source: local,
templates: {
empty: [
  '<div class="empty-message">',
    'unable to find any product that match the current query',
  '</div>'
].join('\n'),
suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{product}}</strong> – {{description}}</div>')
}
});
```

That's it. I'm sorry, I just don't know what to do next. I hope someone could help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253261/create-customize-type-head-using-jquery-and-bootstrap-typeahead/

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful! Everything works great, except it  only gives me 5 maximum suggestions. How do I change that?

Comment: Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swingmanryan/gebws2wx/

I know there should be a LIMIT option, I set it to 10 but it still gives me max of 5 suggestions. Thank you, good sir!

Comment: Moved `limit:10` to second object in options http://jsfiddle.net/gebws2wx/1/ , see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981704/typeahead-always-shows-only-5-suggestions-maximum